# Constant password input and resets on Mac

Tags: macos, password, sleep-wake

I got a new MacBook Pro from my job and was pretty excited, but now I try to hold myself from tossing it out the window!

It constantly asks me to enter passwords for installing things, keeps signing out of apps so I need to re-enter again and again on a daily basis, and once every 2 days it wants me to reset my password when I'm logging in after sleep.

I tried disabling the password from the system preferences but the "Require password after sleep" is greyed out! I really struggle to understand the thinking behind this system...

Any Mac experts that can help?

Comment: There are several different questions here and here we can only deal with one at a time. 1)The enter for installing is by design 2) The apps is app dependant so we would need to know more 3) The last looks odd and is worthy of a question - re greyed out is your mac under some form of management by the company - but requiring a password reset is wrong (although if the mac is under company control that could be a stupid decision by them)

Comment: 1) I'll try to live with it, even though it's frustrating to enter a password when installing 20 apps on a new laptop
2) It happens with google apps, my account is connected to the mail and calendar and keeps asking for a password every 2 days
3) yes, the computer is a company property and I understand there are some built in features, but it still doesn't explain the fact I was forced to reset my password on a daily basis whenever I reset the laptop or after a long sleep mode. I wanted to turn this feature off but it's grey...isn't there a way to completely disable these annoying passwords?

Comment: Most of this doesn't sound like a 'Mac thing' so much as a 'modern security thing'. 2) Most online structures do this these days. You should have them saved in your keychain to just automatically re-enter them. [This works for web sites but not for apps.] There's little you can do about it. 3) What do consider to be 'resetting' your password? You mean you have to type it or you have to change it? [If you are using TouchID to sign in, yes, just like the iPhone/Pad it will require your to *actually* sign in every day or two.]

Comment: it asks me to change the password completely... I have it for a week and already changed it 4 times

Comment: Changing password must be being forced by your IT Department, macOS certainly doesn't do it. You might want to point out to them that this has been considered bad practise for at least a decade [Both UK & US security services explain why it is a bad idea, but basically, it's because people either use simple patterns they can remember, or write them down].

Comment: this is weird... I had a Windows laptop before and never encountered these issues... I love the new Mac but it has some features that are borderline stupid

Comment: If everyone was experiencing these severe inconveniences when using a Mac no one would buy them. Can you give us a much more precise problem description?

Comment: Nothing new to add in addition to what I already described. if it happens again I'll take a screenshot, but the third issue is what bugs me the most. once every couple of days, usually during log in after sleep, the system asks me to make a new password. that's most of it. I can't disable the sleep mode, I can't come up with a list of passwords every single day.

Comment: here, just now I got this message when I got logged out of my companies portal again: "Your device isn't up to date with your organization's policies. Check its status and take action in your organization's device management portal."
even though I entered the password earlier today and logged in, now it's got logged out and blocked.

Comment: You definitely need to speak to IT. You appear to have a managed machine, which means they're in charge of pretty much everything. That's definitely not a 'regular' macOS message.